# From within a TSQL block, can I retrieve the originating SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering if I can retrieve the original SQL statement which fired of a particular SQL block.

Say I have a table with an **AFTER INSERT, UPDATE** trigger on it. From within the trigger, I would like to get the full text of the original `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement that fired the trigger.

Is this possible? Mainly I want to be able to do this for logging/debugging purposes.

Comment: Why do you need the actual statement? You can easily reverse engineer the statement using the inserted virtual table and compare to the base table.

Comment: Well, that would show you the actual values, yes, but doesn't help you if some of the values were passed in as result of calculation or function calls in the SQL statement. It also doesn't tell you the nature of the call. For example, was the SQL an `INSERT () VALUES()` or an `INSERT () SELECT FROM` or was it the `NOT MATCHED` clause of a `MERGE` statement?

Comment: What you are looking to do they already make a tool in sql server for.  It is called 'SQL Profiler'.  It captures tons of things when the engine is running and you can record it and study it later.  Much easier than trying to create some of your own homebrew solution.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: Well, I'm looking more for making the system so when debugging is turned on, it would track SQL statements executed in certain triggers, so I can go back and look at our own log files and just pull them out easily.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do something like this in a trigger (nor would I necessarily) but you might try something like this.

```
select top 100 
    q.[text]
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) q
where r.session_id = @@spid
```

Comment: Hmm, looks promising... I'll have to play around and try that later.

Comment: That is going to return `select top 100 q.[text] from sys.exec_requests r ...`

Answer (score 0):

Great question! I use eventdata all the time with ddl triggers, but haven't thought about what to use for dml triggers. I think this is what you're looking for. It's definitely going into my toolbox!

Please note that the code below is for demonstration only. [Returning output from a trigger is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx). In practice, you'd insert the output of the dbcc command into a log table.

```
if schema_id(N'log') is null execute (N'create schema log');
go
if object_id(N'[log].[data]'
         , N'U') is not null
drop table [log].[data];
go
create table [log].[data] (
  [id]       [int] identity(1, 1)
  , [flower] [sysname]);
go
if exists
  (select *
   from   sys.triggers
   where  parent_class = 0
       and name = 'get_log_dml')
 drop trigger [get_log_dml] on database;
go
create trigger [get_log_dml] on [log].[data]
after insert, update
as
  declare @dbcc table (
  [event_type]   [sysname]
  , [parameters] [int]
  , [event_info] [nvarchar](max)
  );
select *
from   inserted;
insert into @dbcc
            ([event_type],[parameters],[event_info])
execute (N'dbcc inputbuffer(@@spid)');
select [event_type]
       , [parameters]
       , [event_info]
from   @dbcc;
go
insert into [log].[data]
        ([flower])
values      (N'rose');
```